# Customizing Django Admin Result List

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

How can I change the output result from Django Admin Result List? I've been looking into the **change_result_list.html** template file but all I can find is :

```
{% for item in result %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}
```

Which will be outputting something like :

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="action-select" value="2" name="_selected_action" />
    </td>
    <th>
        <a href="1/">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Obviously, the **th** element breaks my design. Is there anyway to change it into **td**?

Answer (score 3):

There's no "easy" way to do it, so I must first ask why exactly you need to do this at all. I don't see why the `<th>` element should "obviously" break your design. The `<th>` element is equivalent to `<td>`, except that is has extra styling by default (usually `font-weight: bold; text-align: center;`). You should be able to account for this in your CSS.

That said, here are some avenues to look at. The th/td choice is determined on line 169 (Django 1.2.1) of `django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list.py`. Here's a snipped summary of the context it appears in:

```
def items_for_result(cl, result, form):
    first = True
    for field_name in cl.list_display:
        # ...
        if (first and not cl.list_display_links) or field_name in cl.list_display_links:
            table_tag = {True:'th', False:'td'}[first]
            first = False
            # ...
            yield mark_safe(u'<%s%s><a href="%s"%s>%s</a></%s>' % (table_tag, row_class, url, ...)
        else:
            # ...
            yield mark_safe(u'<td%s>%s</td>' % (row_class, result_repr))
```

As you can see, there's no obvious way to alter the behaviour that determines the value of table_tag, so some of the options you have are:

- Define a "items_for_result" templatetag that calls the one above and replaces any `<th>`s in the yielded values with `<td>`s. Then you can override "change_list.html" and {% load %} the tag after "admin_list" is loaded.
- Edit the Django code. You'll regret it later though.
- If you're OK with none of the columns in the table being a link to the edit page for the item (I can't imagine why you would), you can use this ugly hack in your `admin.py`:

  ```
  admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
  admin.site._registry[YourModel].list_display_links = ['not_a_field_name',]`
  ```

  Since the admin models are only validated once, which happens when `register()` is called, you can fetch the registered `ModelAdmin` afterwards and give it an invalid `list_display_links` property.

Comment: Indeed, editing the CSS is much easier. However, from usability point of view (and my idealism), th should only be used for a header cell. It's just kind of ridiculous why they use th instead of td.